# delete line after match when end specific letter. regex

Tags: regex

I have a problem with a regex, i should delete the NOP line only when the previous line starting with #/ and ends with the letter E

```
SFIFIPII2#/TEST/APPTEST1/KJOBA01
 FOLLOWS KTEST1

SFIFIPII2#/TEST3/APPTEST12/KJOBA03E
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST14D
 
SFIFIPII4#/TEST5/APPTEST3/KJOBA04
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST15

SFIFIPII23#/TEST2/APPTEST13/KJOBA018
 FOLLOWS KTEST15

SFIFIPII26#/TEST7/APPTEST18/KJOBA01AE
 AT 0600 
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST1B
 
SFIFIPII23#/TEST2/APPTEST11/KJOBA01C
 AT 0600 
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST1S

SFIFIPII2A#/TESTD/APPTEST1F/KJOBA01D
 FOLLOWS KTEST1S

SFIFIPII2N#/TEST/APPTEST1V/KJOBTESTE
 AT 0600 
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST11
 FOLLOWS KTEST12
 FOLLOWS KTEST11

SFIFIPII2#/TEST/APPTEST1/KJOBA01LS
NEEDS 1 MANAGER_XA#RA0E2AB
 FOLLOWS KTEST12

SFIFIPII2#/TEST3/APPTEST12/KJOBA08E
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST14D
```

with this regex i was able to locate the line starting with #/ and ending with letter E

`^.*#\/.*E$`

in this example the result is:

```
SFIFIPII2#/TEST3/APPTEST12/KJOBA03E

SFIFIPII26#/TEST7/APPTEST18/KJOBA01AE

SFIFIPII2N#/TEST/APPTEST1V/KJOBTESTE

SFIFIPII2#/TEST3/APPTEST12/KJOBA08E
```

however i don't know how to delete its corresponding NOP line:

there are two cases, one with the NOP line immediately after it, the second case is that NOP line it is found two lines after.

```
SFIFIPII2#/TEST3/APPTEST12/KJOBA03E
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST14D

SFIFIPII26#/TEST7/APPTEST18/KJOBA01AE
 AT 0600 
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KTEST1B
```

https://regex101.com/r/FhdPKf/1

i'm use a editor text with search and replace regex support. (textpad, editpad, pspad)

some advice, thanks.

Regards

Italo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capture group to keep what you want after the replacement, and match the line with NOP to be removed.

In the replacement use capture group 1.

```php
^(.*#\/.*E(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*NOP$).*)*)\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*NOP$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*#\/.*E` Match a line that contains `#/` and ends on `E`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*NOP$).*` Match a newline, and the rest of the line if it does not start with optional spaces and NOP
  - `)*` Close group and optionally repeat to match all lines
- `)` Close group 1
- `\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*NOP` Match a newline, optional whitespace chars without newlines and `NOP`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/piYof8/1)

You might for example also make the pattern a bit more restricted to not cross matching empty lines, or lines that also contain `/#` and end with an `E` char inbetween before matching `NOP`:

```php
^(.*#/.*E(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*(?:NOP)?$|.*#/.*E$).*)*)\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*NOP$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU9WLV/1)

Comment: thanks very much for your regex code.