# select block text if match specific line, regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

following the advice from From Review i'm open a new Question thread, the previous Questios it's: [delete line after match when end specific letter. regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69654105/) (delete line after match when end specific letter. regex)

I have another need with another question, should i select to copy in another files an entire block only if NOP line has the previous line starting with #/ and ends with the letter E the block is always start with line SCHEDULE and always finish with line END

in this example is true (NOP line has the previous line starting with #/ and ends with the letter E) and should select all block:

- select an entire block to cut in another file.
- the block is always start with line SCHEDULE and always finish with line END
- only if NOP line has the previous line starting with #/ and ends with the letter E

the block is:

```
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#KAAABBBR 
DESCRIPTION "Added by default."
ON RUNCYCLE KAAABBBR VALIDTO 09/24/2021 $RCG KAAABBBR
:
S89AAAABBB1#/XAAA/XCCCDDDD/KA0EG014
 FOLLOWS KABBBCCC3


S89AAAABBB1#/XAAA/XCCCDDDD/KAHHHTTTTTE
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KABBBCCC3


S89AAAABBB1#/XAAA/XCCCDDDD/KAHHHTTTTTS
 NOP
 FOLLOWS MANAGER_XA#KZZZDDDD.KGGGHHHHHE 

END
```

however, there may be other SCHEDULE block with jobs that end with the letter E **but are not NOP and should not be taken into consideration.**

```
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#KBBBCCCR 
DESCRIPTION "Added by default."
ON RUNCYCLE KAAABBBR VALIDTO 09/24/2021 $RCG KBBBCCCR 
:
S89AAAABBB1#/XBBB/XCCCDDDD/KA0EG014
 FOLLOWS KABBBCCC3

S89AAAABBB1#/XBBB/XCCCDDDD/KAHHHTTTE
 FOLLOWS KABBBCCC3

S89AAAABBB1#/XBBB/XCCCDDDD/KAHHHTTTTTS
 NOP
 FOLLOWS MANAGER_XA#KZZZDDDD.KGGGHHHHHE 

END
```

with this code search line starting with #/ and ends with the letter E and remove line NOP (thanks The fourth bird)

```
^(.*#\/.*E(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*NOP$).*)*)\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*NOP$
```

any advice please.

Thansk

Regards.

Italo

EDIT UPDATE:

yes, the second example it's ok but

when it finds the match, it must select the entire block it belongs to copy text block to another file.

when match it's true

```
S89AAAABBB1#/XAAA/XCCCDDDD/KAHHHTTTTTE
 NOP
```

it should select all text block (start line SCHEDULE a finish in line END), this:

```
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#KAAABBBR 
DESCRIPTION "Added by default."
ON RUNCYCLE KAAABBBR VALIDTO 09/24/2021 $RCG KAAABBBR
:
S89AAAABBB1#/XAAA/XCCCDDDD/KA0EG014
 FOLLOWS KABBBCCC3


S89AAAABBB1#/XAAA/XCCCDDDD/KAHHHTTTTTE
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KABBBCCC3


S89AAAABBB1#/XAAA/XCCCDDDD/KAHHHTTTTTS
 NOP
 FOLLOWS MANAGER_XA#KZZZDDDD.KGGGHHHHHE 

END
```

Regards.

Italo

Comment: So for the second example there should be no match? https://regex101.com/r/zlNMnI/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?s)^SCHEDULE(?:.(?!^END$))*?#\/[^\r\n]*E\r?\n[ \t]*NOP$.*?^END$
```

If in your regex tool doesn´t work `(?s)` (dot matches also newlines), then replace `.` with `(?:.|\s)`or any expression for *any character*.

Please note that the quantifiers `*?` are enforced *lazy* to avoid taking characters from the next block (after END).

[Regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/vk331r/2/)

Comment: thanks for answer, your regex match this case: https://regex101.com/r/uyDxXk/1 but the line NOP it's not always right after line`#/*E` sometimes it is after other lines, in this code https://regex101.com/r/TMaiJF/1 not match because line NOP is after line FOLLOWS. please see. thanks again.

Comment: If we assume that there cannot be an empty line between the # line and the NOP line, we would have to add this subexpression to match those intermediate lines:
 `(?:(?!^$).)*?`
The new expression is [here.](https://regex101.com/r/RZGSh7/1)

Comment: thanks JGomez, your regex that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the line starting with SCHEDULE till the first line that contains `#/` and ends on `E` and the next line is `NOP`

Then continue matching all lines until you match `END`

During the match, you can check that you do not cross matching END to prevent matching too much.

```php
^SCHEDULE\b.*(?:\n(?!(?:.*#\/.*E|END)$).*)*\r?\n.*#\/.*E\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*NOP(?:\r?\n(?!END$).*)*\r?\nEND$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `SCHEDULE\b.*` Match SCHEDULE and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!(?:.*#\/.*E|END)$).*` Match a line that does not have `#/` and end on E or are `END`
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat so it can also be the immediate next line
- `\r?\n.*#\/.*E` Match the line that has `#/` and ends with `E`
- `\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*NOP` Match the line with `NOP`
- `(?:\r?\n(?!END$).*)*` Match all lines that are not `END`
- `\r?\nEND` Match a newline and `END`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/shv5j4/1/)

Comment: thanks for answer, the regex not match this case: https://regex101.com/r/Muvxu2/1  another info, the line NOP it's not always right after `\r?\n.*#\/.*E` sometimes it is after other lines, like this: https://regex101.com/r/hsTIYs/1 thanks.

Comment: @italo_pm In that case, you can use be more specific about what you would allow to match after and in between matches: `^SCHEDULE\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!SCHEDULE|.*#\/.*E$|END$).*)*\r?\n.*#\/.*E(?:\r?\n(?!SCHEDULE|.*#\/|END$|[^\S\r\n]*NOP).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*NOP(?:\r?\n(?!END).*)*\r?\nEND$` See https://regex101.com/r/xqJcBk/1

Comment: thanks, but regex not match this. even if it exists it does not find match
 please see https://regex101.com/r/hl3PIB/1  (find KG34G21CR1E)