# how to find value from first specific match result (another line) , regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm Update Question:

open a new Question thread, the previous Questions are [delete line after match when end specific letter. regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69654105) and [select block text if match specific line, regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663382) unlike those questions i would need to select a line based on the match result from another line.

would help the line SCHEDULE to select the block text and match last word to then find again in block text the word ending with the letter E and always have # symbol.

block text start line SCHEDULE a finish in line END (to copy in another file)

in any case SCHEDULE line have the # symbol

```
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#KGDIVAGBLR 
or
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#KGICROBLR_2 
or
SCHEDULE MASTERAGENTS#KGICRO741_AABB
or
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#/XAAA/KAAA/KGICROZZZ
or
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#/XAAA/KAAA/KGFLABUR_4
or
SCHEDULE MASTERAGENTS#/KA0H/KA0HM00_FACT/KA0HM00_FACT 

END
```

for example block text (start line SCHEDULE a finish in line END):

```
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#/XAAA/KAAA/KGICROZZZ
DESCRIPTION "Added by default."
:
S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1086
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KG34G1085

S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KGICROZZZE
 FOLLOWS KG34G493
 FOLLOWS KG34G522

S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1086
 NOP
 FOLLOWS KG34G1085

END
```

and word KGICROZZZE it's to match because starting with name from last word in SCHEDULE line and finish in letter E

if in SCHEDULE line the last word finished in KGFLABUR_4 (underscore + another word) the match is before underscore to can find in text block KGFLABURE

```
SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#/XAAA/KAAA/KGFLABUR_4

S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KGFLABURE

or 

S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KGFLABURE_4
```

I would need them 2 regex:

- one to identify line in block text starting with name from last word in SCHEDULE line and finish in letter E and related SCHEDULE block text.

follow block text example:

```
    SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#/XAAA/KAAA/KGICROZZZ
    DESCRIPTION "Added by default."
    :
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1086
     NOP
     FOLLOWS KG34G1085
    
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KGICROZZZE
     FOLLOWS KG34G493
     FOLLOWS KG34G522
     NOP
    
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1086
     NOP
     FOLLOWS KG34G1085
    
    END
```

or in this case SCHEDULE line finished in KAAABBB_CCC the match is before underscore KAAABBB

```
    SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#/XAAA/KAAA/KAAABBB_CCC
    DESCRIPTION "Added by default."
    :
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1086
     NOP
     FOLLOWS KG34G1085
    
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KAAABBBE_CCC
     FOLLOWS KG34G493
     FOLLOWS KG34G522
    
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1086
     NOP
     FOLLOWS KG34G1085
    
    END
```

- one to identify line in block text NOT HAVE line starting with name from last word in SCHEDULE line and finish in letter E

follow block text example:

```
    SCHEDULE MANAGER_XA#/XAAA/KAAA/KXXXYYYY
    DESCRIPTION "Added by default."
    :
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1086
     NOP
     FOLLOWS KG34G1085
    
    S89COLENG2#/KG34/KG34G43CR3/KG34G1020
     NOP
     FOLLOWS KG34G1085
    
    END
```

I apologize if the text is too long but I also had to write the examples to be able to explain myself better. I also tried to shorten it. if you need more information please let me know to update the Question.

Regards.

Italo

Comment: How about this? Regex: `SCHEDULE.*\/([^_]+)(?:.|\r?\n)+(^.*\1E.*)\n((?:^ +.*\n)*)` Your match can be found in group 2  https://regex101.com/r/P6v9gE/2

Comment: Also in single line mode `/SCHEDULE[^\n]*\/([^_]+)[^\n]*$.*(^[^\n]+\1E[^\n]*)((?:\n [^\n]+)+)/gms` https://regex101.com/r/yNEuk8/1

Comment: Daniel, thanks for answer, i'm update question, please see again. your regex that's correct though but not select all block text after match the line. (block text starting in line SCHEDULE and finished in line END and does not consider case with SCHEDULE line only have # , finding only # in SCHEDULE line would also be fine. thanks again.

Comment: Try [this one for match](https://regex101.com/r/P6v9gE/5) `SCHEDULE.*\/([^_\n]+)(?=(?:[\n]|.)+\1E)(?:\n|.)+?(^.*?\1E.*)(?:\n|.)+?END` and [this one for no match](https://regex101.com/r/DcdJcN/1/) `SCHEDULE.*\/([^_\/\n]+)(?:(?:_|\b)[^\/]+$)(?!(?:.|\n)*\1E)(?:.|\n)+?END`

Comment: thanks Daniel, in this case (for match) regex not match https://regex101.com/r/Bi84KR/1 
 SCHEDULE line have only symbol # in all case maybe find to match with # sybol and not with / another in this case (for no match) regex code not match this: https://regex101.com/r/JmYypN/1 always with # symbol in SCHEDULE line.. however in my editor text editpad lite when execute search option see this message: "your regular expression leads to "catastrophic backtracking" making it too complex to be run to complete."  the file have 117000 lines any ideas? thanks again for your help.

Comment: With that many lines I'm thinking you're probably better off first matching on just `SCHEDULE.*?END` and getting all the individual SCHEDULE <--> END blocks first.  Then take each of those blocks and run through each of those on both both regex blocks.  You likely cannot do this in editpad but I can provide you an answer that you can use in PowerShell if it's available to you.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks again, with this regex matched all case block SCHEDULE <--> END  in my text editor, https://regex101.com/r/LQbkRL/1 with this regex `(?sm)SCHEDULE(.|\n)*?END$`  the END line is last from block and have only word END (I say because perhaps there is an END word among the other words (ENDJOIN EVERYENDTIME and another).), unfortunately I could not use powershell because is blocked. I would stay if possible with the code regex for my editor please, in my editor can selected all match and copy or cut selection to another file. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, here is an example (in PowerShell) of how I would first grab all the individual SCHEDULE <--> END blocks and then separate those out into matched and not matched groups using the regex that checks for match.

```
# Read lines from file into $text variable
$text = Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\temp\powershell\schedule.log

# Use regex class to find all SCHEDULE <--> END blocks in $text
$scheduleBlockMatches = [regex]::matches($text, '(?sm)SCHEDULE.*?END')

# Define matching pattern in a variable called $matchPattern
$matchPattern = '(?m)SCHEDULE.*[\/#]([^_\n]+)(?=(?:[\n]|.)+\1E)(?:\n|.)+?(^.*?\1E.*)(?:\n|.)+?END'

# For each SCHEDULE <--> END block in $scheduledBlockMatches use Where() to see if it matches pattern
# Specifying split as an argument to Where() will give us both both true and false sets
# which will be placed in our specified variables '$matched' and '$notMatched'
$matched, $notmatched = $scheduleBlockMatches.Value.Where({ $_ -match $matchPattern }, 'split')

# Create a simple object to display the counts of and first examples of each collection
[PSCustomObject]@{
    TotalLinesInLog     = ($text -split '\n').Count
    TotalScheduleBlocks = $scheduleBlockMatches.Count
    MatchedCount        = $matched.Count
    NotMatchedCount     = $notmatched.Count
    FirstMatched        = $matched[0]
    FirstNotMatched     = $notmatched[0]
}
```

Output of the custom object would look like this

```
TotalLinesInLog     : 228696
TotalScheduleBlocks : 15120
MatchedCount        : 9450
NotMatchedCount     : 5670
FirstMatched        : SCHEDULE MASTERAGENTS#KA96G01
                      DESCRIPTION "Added by composer."
                      :

                      S89COLENG2#/KA96/KA96G01/KA96G065
                       FOLLOWS KA96G030

                      S89COLENG2#/KA96/KA96G01/KA96G01E
                       FOLLOWS KA96G036
                       FOLLOWS KA96G038

                      MASTERAGENTS#SBP_KA96G114_KA96G09_KA96G112
                       FOLLOWS KA96G114

                      END
FirstNotMatched     : SCHEDULE MASTERAGENTS#KA96GAA_5
                      DESCRIPTION "Added by composer."
                      :

                      S89COLENG2#/KA96/KA96G02/KA96G091
                       FOLLOWS KA96G090


                      S89COLENG2#/KA96/KA96G02/KA96G096
                       FOLLOWS KA96G060

                      END
```

Comment: Thanks very much Daniel for share powershell code, I have no idea how to save each
matched or notMatched block text in specific file, another unfortunately I could not use powershell because is blocked on my company for my group users. I would stay if possible with the code regex for my editor please, in my editor can selected all match and copy or cut selection to another file. would stay if that's okay with regex codes for you.